# What is "session_engaged" event property of "session_start" in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, events, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm working with Firebase analytics and I'm trying to figure out the best way to track the engagement of our (iOS app) users. 
I see that there are multiple events and properties related to engagement, such as the "user_engagement" event (and the "engagement_time_msec" property) and "ga_session".
User engagement seems a bit too low-level/frequent. It basically happens any time the user touches the screen and after booting the app I see that it is often sent 2/3 times ever before interacting with the app itself.
While trying to find a better solution I stumbled across another event property, which is called "session_start" and *sometimes* it comes with a property called "session_engaged". It appears to be a bool or a counter (it's always 1 as far as I saw).
I could not find any documentation on this event and property.

Anybody who can give me more info on that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**session_start** is when a user engages the app for more than the minimum session duration after a period of inactivity that exceeds the session timeout duration.

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en&ref_topic=6317484